# Approval workflow doesn't work SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to set up a knowledge base using enterprise wiki pages in SharePoint 2013.

Now I'm trying to set up a workflow: Newly created or edited wiki pages have to be approved by the administrator first.

I have tried using the approval workflow that allready in sharepoint but it doesn't seem to work. My users see everything even the unapproved items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which list did you choose for the tasks in Sharepoint Designer. If you are system admin, the workflow doesn't start automatically. You have to start it manually.

Comment: I've chose the pages library of my enterprise wiki site. I thought this was the right one since every new page is added there?

Comment: I think you have to choose a "list" to see the tasks. There is a default list called "task list" in Site Content. Can you check if it is there? The page library that you add is a different thing from the workflow.

Comment: I see workflow task in my site content. it has allot of items in it.

Comment: So your workflow works. You can approve/reject through this list too. You have to set the list settings for the views. For example if you don't want users don't see the unapproval items, in the "View"(which view you use for the lists) add a condition for show items only when Approval Status is equal to Approved. Users who has full control for lists/libriaries don't effect through these conditions.

Comment: oke so that's why users still see unapproved items! But one last question will my users will be able to search these unapproved items?

Comment: I can't say anything about searching. I don't know. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you have already setup the approval workflow for the wiki site then you should make sure to enable the Content Approval for your wiki site. By default this is turned off and as such users with read access will see everything even if the items are still in draft phase. So what you need to do is enable content approval first and in the content approval screen make sure that draft items can only be seen by approvers.